# DataTables : search in multiple columns using OR operator

Tags: javascript, datatable

I try to search in multiple columns using the same value, by default the values exist on the table and if I search in one column using this code, it's working correctly without any problem :

```
table.column(0).search('blabla\\s*$', true, false).draw()
```

if I try to search on the second column using other value, it's work to correctly :

```
table.column(1).search('bla\\s*$', true, false).draw()
```

So, I try to search on the two columns using this code ( I found it on StackOverflow and Officiel DataTable documentation )

```
table.columns([0, 1]).search('bla\\s*$', true, false).draw()
```

but it's doesn't work, So, I analyze it and I found the `datatable` search use the AND operator, which means `'bla'` need to exist on the two columns, but I want to use the OR operator.

I try to create my custom filter, but it has many problems in addition to the heaviness in implementation, is there any solution to use OR operator on search columns of datatables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a custom plugin using `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` and since it's just an array of functions you can use that fact to activate and deactivate the filter as you wish

```
myfilter = function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
var str1 = data[0]
var str2 = data[1]
if (str1.search(/bla\\s*$/g) != -1 || str2.search(/bla\\s*$/g) != -1) {
  return true;
}
return false;
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(myfilter)
```

to remove the filter you simply do

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.splice($.fn.dataTable.ext.search.indexOf(myfilter, 1));
```

Comment: The first solution it's doesn't work, about custom filter I use it but it has many problems, it crashed when I need to remove to filter ( restore the default table )

Comment: can you elaborate the last part of your comments i didn't get it

Comment: When I add the custom filter it's work fine when I do a search, but when I want to remove the filter I can't get back the full table, any solution?

Comment: I have updated the answer check it out and let me know if it works for you